# Maximum no.of connections that can be held by s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am learning about Amazon Web services. I just want to know what is the maximum number of connections(roughly) that can be held by Amazon S3 simultaneously without crashing...

Comment: Amazon don't expose any limits of concurrent downloads/connections to S3 so in theory it is unlimited, of course in practice it isn't, but as with any CDN it depends on so many things that it's very difficult to predict. You alone wouldn't make S3 crash though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Theoretically this is infinite. To achieve this, they use a partitioning scheme they explain here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html

Basically they partition your buckets on different servers based on the first few characters of the filename. If those are random, you scale indefinitely (they just take more characters to partition on). If you prepend all files with `file_` or something (so S3 cannot partition the files correctly because all files have the same starting characters), the limit is about 300 GET / sec or 100 PUT/DELETE/POST per second.

See that page for an in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Given the AWS documentation you will receive `HTTP 503 Slow Down` over **3,500** PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE or **5,500** GET/HEAD requests per second.

The limit has been increased in July 2018.

More information :
https://aws.amazon.com/en/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-request-limit-avoid-throttling/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance.html