# What is the connection limit to S3 using AWS SDK Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Is there a connection pool for aws-sdk?

How many concurrent connections can I have to S3 from a single app instance? Is there a config for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you trying to do but check this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html that is also mentioned in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37432967/177154

Also not sure if you have already checked this:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb ?

As a protip - fairly early in the S3 doc article, there is a link to open a support case on AWS support. This might seem odd and it is often neglected by devs but there are reports that opening a case like this could end up with a really good info/solution for whatever the extraordinary case you might have.